# How to insert Persian words into a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, character, persian

I am just wondering how to insert Persian characters into my service-based database?

When I save my data it shows something like `'???'`.

I have checked such questions like this. But, the solutions were not useful.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            objConnection.Open();

            if (ctypeCheckBox.Checked == true)                
                st = 1;          
            else if (ctypeCheckBox.Checked == false)                
                st = 0;

            string query = "INSERT INTO LectureTable(Cname, Cid, Ccredit, Csession, Ctype, CstartDate, CendDate, CstartTime, CendTime) VALUES('" + cnameTextBox.Text + "','" + cidTextBox.Text + "','" + ccreditTextBox.Text + "','" + csessionTextBox.Text + "','" + st + "', '" + cstartDateDateTimePicker.MinDate + "', '" + cendDateDateTimePicker.MaxDate + "', '" + cStartTimeBox.Text + "', '" + cEndTimeBox.Text + "')";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, objConnection);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");

            objConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: If it’s SQLServer you need to prefix your string with N, e.g. `N'text'`, to mark the text as non-ASCII characters. Also you should use SQL parameters, because your query will break if one of your variables contains quotes and thus your users could make use of SQL injection to run random queries, delete your database and so on.

Comment: You might need the correct coallation as well, so the string comparisons work correctly for you - quick google brought me to : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/54fba46c-9792-4172-870c-0d7545235c6a/persian-collation?forum=databasedesign - maybe read up on it.

Comment: Where exactly should put the N in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. Never ever combine your query string with values

   ```
   "INSERT INTO LectureTable(Cname, Cid, Ccredit, Csession, Ctype, CstartDate, CendDate, CstartTime, CendTime) VALUES('" + cnameTextBox.Text + "','" + cidTextBox.Text + "','" + ccreditTextBox.Text + "','" + csessionTextBox.Text + "','" + st + "', '" + cstartDateDateTimePicker.MinDate + "', '" + cendDateDateTimePicker.MaxDate + "', '" + cStartTimeBox.Text + "', '" + cEndTimeBox.Text + "')";
   ```

   Should be immediately replaced with

   ```
   "INSERT INTO LectureTable(Cname, Cid, Ccredit, Csession, Ctype, CstartDate, CendDate, CstartTime, CendTime) 
   VALUES(@cname, @cid, @ccredit, @csession, @st, @cstartDateDate, @cendDate, @cStartTime, @cEndTimeB)";
   ```

and then you should use

```
SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("cname",cnameTextBox.Text);
```

for all parameters. This will save you from a lot of problems including SQL injection.

2. In the database your columns should have `nvarchar` data type.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SqlParameter` .Giving example of only one parameter.You can add others as same way.

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO LectureTable(Cname) VALUES(@name)";          

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SqlConnection))
{ 

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@name", cnameTextBox.Text);
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.String;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
.....
}
```